# Javascript - Removing array item & DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to learn Javascript and so I made a little code, but there is something wrong with it that I can

```
var array = new Array("Apple","Mangosteen","Durian","Pineapples");
...
...
function B() {
    ...
    ...
    var BP = $("<p></p>");
    BP.text("Click \"x\" on items to be removed").append("<br/>");
    for (i=0;i<array.length;i++) {
        var f = array[i];
        var F = $("<div></div>");
        F.attr({"class":"f"});
        var N = $("<span></span>");
        N.attr({"class":"n"});
        N.text(f);
        var d = $("<span></span>");
        d.attr({"class":"cc sl"});
        d.bind("click", function(e){
            e.stopPropagation();
            e.preventDefault();
            IR(f,F);
        });
        d.html("&times;");
    ...
    ...
}
function IR(f,F) {
    var a = array.indexOf(f);
    array.splice(a,1);
    F.remove();
}
```

When I added `console.log(f);` in `function IR()`, the value passed will always be "Pineapples", regardless if I'm clicking "x" on "Apples" or "Durian", the `f` value passed will always be "Pineapples". What is wrong with it?

Comment: Can you please add a fiddle?

Comment: tip: try to use proper naming in your code it will be more readable and understandable, while now who the slice know what A and B are??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You call a function inside a for loop - something you can read more about here [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example).

For now, if you're using ES6. The easiest way to solve it will be using `let` in the for loop.

```
for (let i=0;i<array.length;i++) { ...... }
```

Or else, use `Array.forEach()` instead of the for loop.

In your case it should be something like

```
array.forEach(function(fruit) {
        var f = fruit;
        var F = $("<div></div>");
        F.attr({"class":"f"});
        var N = $("<span></span>");
        N.attr({"class":"n"});
        N.text(c);
        var d = $("<span></span>");
        d.attr({"class":"cc sl"});
        d.bind("click", function(e){
            e.stopPropagation();
            e.preventDefault();
            IR(f,F);
        });
        d.html("&times;");
    ...
    ...
});
```

Comment: Calling a function in a loop is not "a well-known issue in JavaScript". You make it sound as if there's a bug in the language.

Answer (score 1):

its because the scope of variable "i" is global, so `var f = array[i];` will result in `var f = array[3];` so you will get only "Pineapples".
I will give you a simple sample code to understand the issue. please run below code.

```
    <script>
var funcs = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {          // let's create 3 functions
    funcs[i] = function() {            // and store them in funcs
        console.log("My value: " + i); // each should log its value.
    };
}
for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
    funcs[j]();                        // and now let's run each one to see
}
</script>
```

you will get only 3 because "i" is in global scope.

Answer (score 1):

When you declare a variable using ***var*** it will be declared within a scope of the function. That's why when you click 'x' javascript will pass to the IR function the last value of the variables - "Pineapples" and Pineapples's div. If you want to declare a variable within the *'for'* cycle scope, use ***let***. In this case, in every loop of *'for'* cycle javascript will create a new variables f and F.

```
var array = new Array("Apple","Mangosteen","Durian","Pineapples");

function B() {
    var BP = $("<div></div>");
    BP.text("Click \"x\" on items to be removed").append("<br/>");
    for (var i=0;i<array.length;i++) {
        let f = array[i];
        let F = $("<div></div>");
        F.attr({"class":"f"});
        var N = $("<span></span>");
        N.attr({"class":"n"});
        N.text(f);
        var d = $("<span></span>");
        d.attr({"class":"cc sl"});
        d.bind("click", function(e){
            e.stopPropagation();
            e.preventDefault();
            IR(f,F);
        });
        d.html("&times;");
        F.append(N).append(d)
        BP.append(F)
      }
}
function IR(f,F) {
    var a = array.indexOf(f);
    array.splice(a,1);
    F.remove();
}
```